# what is the difference between npm, grunt and webpack in terms of their application?

Tags: npm, webpack, gruntjs

which tool among those in above is used to solve what sort of problem? The simplified and straight to the point answer the better.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some pretty good descriptions of each of these with a basic Google search.

In short, npm is a software repository. Grunt is a tool used bring together multiple javascript tasks into single commands. Webpack is a powerful module bundler, allowing you to bring together javascript, css, html from various sources (one being npm) and bundle them in such a way that you can be left with a single javascript module containing all the code you require.

> The World's Largest Software Registry (Library)
> npm is the world's largest Software Registry.
>
> The registry contains over 800,000 code packages.
>
> Open-source developers use npm to share software.

[What is NPM @ W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_npm.asp)

> Grunt is a JavaScript task runner, a tool used to automatically perform frequent tasks such as minification, compilation, unit testing, and linting. It uses a command-line interface to run custom tasks defined in a file (known as a Gruntfile). Grunt was created by Ben Alman and is written in Node.js. It is distributed via npm.

[What is Grunt @ Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grunt_(software))

> webpack is an open-source JavaScript module bundler.[5][6][7][8] It is made primarily for JavaScript, but it can transform front-end assets such as HTML, CSS, and images if the corresponding loaders are included.[9] webpack takes modules with dependencies and generates static assets representing those modules.[10]
>
> Webpack takes the dependencies and generates a dependency graph allowing web developers to use a modular approach for their web application development purposes

[What is Webpack @ Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack)

Answer (score 0):

**difference between grunt and webpack**

`grunt` is stream management tools that perform functions required by users through task configuration, such as format verification, code compression, etc. It is worth mentioning that the code processed by `grunt` is only replaced by local variable names and simplified. Nothing has changed, it's still your code.

While `webpack` has carried out a more thorough packaging process, and is more inclined to transform the module grammar rules. The main task is to break through the gap between browsers, analyze, compress, merge, and package various static files that are not originally recognized by the browser, and finally generate the code supported by the browser. Therefore, the code after `webapck` has been packaged. It’s not the code you wrote, maybe if you look at it again, you can’t understand it anymore.

---

**npm is more like providing building enviroment**

`npm` is a package management tool installed with NodeJS. It can solve many problems in NodeJS code deployment. Common usage scenarios are as follows:

- Allow users to download third-party packages written by others from the NPM server to local use.
- Allow users to download and install command line programs written by others from - the NPM server for local use.
- Allow users to upload their own packages or command line programs to the NPM server for others to use.

`npm` is more like providing build enviroment, but `grunt` and `webpack` is working as building tools.